# How to open an item from RecyclerView to another according to its title - MYSQL Database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-recyclerview

I listed all my data from the MySQL database to RecyclerView. Recently, the RecyclerView cannot clickable and only display all the list. Thus, I want to know the code to redirect the selected item in RecyclerView to another activity. For example, in RecyclerView, there a list of "Title 1, Title 2, Title 3". When I click on "Title 1", it will redirect to another activity with all content from "Title 1". Below is my Code:

//Main Activity

```
private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://10.0.2.2/listview/Api.php";

//a list to store all the products
List<Product> productList;

//the recyclerview
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the recyclerview from xml
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //initializing the productlist
    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    //this method will fetch and parse json
    //to display it in recyclerview
    loadProducts();

}

private void loadProducts() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        //traversing through all the object
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            //getting product object from json array
                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            //adding the product to product list
                            productList.add(new Product(
                                    product.getInt("id"),
                                    product.getString("title"),
                                    product.getString("name"),
                                    product.getString("time")
                            ));
                        }

                        //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                        ProductsAdapter adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

//Products Adapter

```
private Context mCtx;
private List<Product> productList;

public ProductsAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, null);
    return new ProductViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Product product = productList.get(position);

    holder.tvName.setText(product.getTitle());
    holder.tvTitle.setText(product.getName());
    holder.tvTime.setText(product.getTime());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvName, tvTitle, tvTime;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    }
}
```

//Product

```
public Product(int id, String title, String name, String time) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.name = name;
    this.time = time;

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

//PHP

```
//database constants
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'listview');

//connecting to database and getting the connection object
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//Checking if any error occured while connecting
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

//creating a query
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, title, name, time FROM products;");

//executing the query 
$stmt->execute();

//binding results to the query 
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $name, $time);

$products = array(); 

//traversing through all the result 
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['id'] = $id; 
    $temp['title'] = $title; 
    $temp['name'] = $name; 
    $temp['time'] = $time;  
    array_push($products, $temp);
}

//displaying the result in json format 
echo json_encode($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Set Click Event by creating an interface class for callback witch you can pass int her adapter constructor then use as adapter member then pass that callback when you create the view holder to the view holder constructor then set click listener to item by implementing the View.OnClickListener and set the click to item then when the onClick Called call the the callback we created this is little confusion but you can follow the [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9)